# function only runs once even though use forEach() Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I want to make the numbers increase onclick using the snippet that I got and named it "numberIncrease()". But the problem is the function only run for the first h1. I tried console.log inside the forEach loop and it does detect both elements.

Why is it that my code only runs for one of the numbers? the forEach does detect both .counter, but it doesn't show in the code.

Should I try different types of loops?

```
<button id="button">test</button>
<h2 class="counter" data-count-start="500">788</h2>
<h2 class="counter" data-count-start="333">666</h2>


<script>
let test = true;
const button = document.getElementById('button');
let counter = document.querySelector('.counter');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (test) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.counter').forEach(counter=>{
      numberIncrease();
      console.log(counter)
    })
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }

})

function numberIncrease() {
  const counter = document.querySelector(".counter");
  const tl = gsap.timeline();
  const reducedMotion = window.matchMedia("(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)")
  .matches;

  animateCount(counter);

  function animateCount(el) {
    const start = removeCommas(el.dataset.countStart);
    const end = removeCommas(el.textContent);

    tl.fromTo(
      el,
      {
        innerText: start,
        "--font-variation-weight": 300,
        scale: reducedMotion ? 1 : 0.99
      },
      {
        innerText: end,
        snap: { innerText: 1 },
        duration: reducedMotion ? 0 : 3,
        ease: "linear",
        onUpdate: () => {
          el.innerHTML = formatNumber(el.innerText);
        }
      }
    ).to(el, {
      scale: 1,
      "--font-variation-weight": 600,
      ease: "elastic.out(1, 0.2)",
      duration: 1.2
    });
  }

  function celebrate() {
    setCelebrateClass(true);
  }

  function setCelebrateClass(enabled) {
    counter.classList.toggle("celebrate", enabled);
  }

  function removeCommas(num) {
    return num.replace(/,/g, "");
  }

  function formatNumber(num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I just executed your code and it prints `788` and `666` to the console, hence `forEach` runs twice.

Comment: You are using `document.querySelector('.counter')` so it will only select the first one

Comment: @uminder it doesn't run twice if I call the numberIncrease() function.

Comment: @MeL I'm still new with javascript, should I use querySelectorAll instead?

Comment: Yes, the result of which will give you a node list, which you can then loop over with `forEach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <button id="button">test</button>
    <h1 class="counter" data-count-start="500">788</h1>
    <h1 class="counter" data-count-start="333">666</h1>


    <script>
        let test = true;
        const button = document.getElementById('button');
        let counter = document.querySelector('.counter');
        
        function numberIncrease(counter) { //edited line
            if (counter) {//edited line
                const tl = gsap.timeline();
                const reducedMotion = window.matchMedia("(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)")
                    .matches;

                animateCount(counter);

                function animateCount(el) {
                    const start = removeCommas(el.dataset.countStart);
                    const end = removeCommas(el.textContent);

                    tl.fromTo(
                        el, {
                            innerText: start,
                            "--font-variation-weight": 300,
                            scale: reducedMotion ? 1 : 0.99
                        }, {
                            innerText: end,
                            snap: {
                                innerText: 1
                            },
                            duration: reducedMotion ? 0 : 3,
                            ease: "linear",
                            onUpdate: () => {
                                el.innerHTML = formatNumber(el.innerText);
                            }
                        }
                    ).to(el, {
                        scale: 1,
                        "--font-variation-weight": 600,
                        ease: "elastic.out(1, 0.2)",
                        duration: 1.2
                    });
                }

                function celebrate() {
                    setCelebrateClass(true);
                }

                function setCelebrateClass(enabled) {
                    counter.classList.toggle("celebrate", enabled);
                }

                function removeCommas(num) {
                    return num.replace(/,/g, "");
                }

                function formatNumber(num) {
                    return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
                }

                console.dir(counter);
            } else {
                console.error('Counter not found!') //edited line
            }
        }

        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (test) {
                console.log('yes');
                document.querySelectorAll('.counter').forEach(counter => {
                    numberIncrease(counter); //edited line
                    console.log()
                })
            } else {
                console.log('no');
            }

        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).